# Return same type as class in C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to have a C++ class method to return a reference to a same-class object. This should also work for derived classes. In the following example I simply put 'A*' as a return-type of the function, but this is obviously a problem when using class B.

```
class A {
public:
    A* self() { return this; };
};

class B: public A {

};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A* a1 = new A;
    B* b1 = new B;

    A* a2 = a1->self();
    B* b2 = b1->self();
}
```

The compiler complains with

> class.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: class.cpp:16: error:
>   invalid conversion from ‘A*’ to ‘B*’

In Objective-C I would have used the `instanceof`
 special type as a return type. Is there anything similar to use in C++ or any known pattern for such problems?

Comment: Would dynamic_cast<> work here?

Comment: You're trying to set a B* to an A*. Did you want self to return an B*?

Comment: The short answer is No. Functions have a single, fixed type; you cannot have a function whose type changes when the class is derived from.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, B->self() should return a pointer to B.

Comment: What is the prupose of that? `a1->self()` would return pointer to `a1`, which you have anyway. What is the actual problem vs your attempted solution? Are you trying to find a way to inspect derived class type?

Comment: @W.B. This was just a simple example. The actual (base) class has a static map of all current instantiated objects of that type and methods to search for objects with a specific values of properties (of the base class)

Answer (score 5):

I guess you need ["return type relaxation"](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA596&lpg=PA596&dq=return%20type%20relaxation%20c%2b%2b&source=bl&ots=DpAsJka27J&sig=EPr7_VNhjNllgT1ok4I1nC97bNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7RBeU4ymHMG5rgfH24BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=return%20type%20relaxation%20c%2b%2b&f=false) (notice `virtual`):

```
struct A {
    virtual A* self() { return this; };
};

struct B: A {
    B* self() { return this; };
};
```

You may also consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259853/whats-the-best-signature-for-clone-in-c)
This language feature introduced specifically for the case when you have parallel hierarchies of classes (`clone` is special case)

Comment: But re-implementing the same functionality in B would case duplicate code which I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: You can't avoid this in C++.

Comment: @TobiasMüller idioms that work fine in other languages may be not the best practices in C++. In your example, why do you need this "self" operation? I guess you are trying to implement some conditional logic based on dynamic type. In C++ people usually use virtual functions for that.

Comment: @AlexT The base function has a static map of all instantiated objects which can be searched by properties of the (base) class. When this search is done on the child class I'd like it to return a child class.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is indeed invalid. For such conversions, you need to cast :

```
B* b2 = static_cast<B*>( b1->self() );
```

But the proper way is to try to avoid getting into such situation, either with proper design, or refactoring.

Comment: This is my current way of "solving" the problem, but I don't like it and hoped for a more elegant solution.