# Copy-constructor when using inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a problem with a school assignment. I am supposed to create a system that keeps track of contenders in a sporting event. I have a base class contender and two classes that derive from that called `Professional` and `Exerciser`.
And then I have a register class that contains a `Contender **contenders`. And I have to create a copy-constructor for this class but I don't know how to do it.

I thought about something like this

```
Register::Register(const Register& original)
{
    this->kap = original.kap;
    this->currentAmount = original.currentAmount;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->currentAmount; i++)
    {
        if (Professional* pro = dynamic_cast<Professional*>(this->contenders[i]))
        {
            this->contenders[i] = new Professional(*original.contenders[i]);
        }
        if (Exerciser* pro = dynamic_cast<Exerciser*>(this->contenders[i]))
        {
            this->contenders[i] = new Exerciser(*original.contenders[i]);
        }
    }
    this->initiate(this->currentAmount);
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're having with this code? You might want to look at the [virtual constructor idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor) (particularly the virtual copy).

Comment: But then the `Register` class needs to know about all the possible derived classes. Perhaps you can give the base class a `virtual Base* clone() const;` member function, which all derived classes implement as `Base* clone() const { return new Derived (*this); }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259853/whats-the-best-signature-for-clone-in-c

Comment: What type is `this->contenders`? Depending on the type you might have undefined behavior. (It should really be a vector.)

Comment: It tells me that "there is no instance of constructor Professional::Professional that matches the argument list argument types are:(Contender)". And we are not suppose to use vectors on this assignment I can post all of the code if you would like

Comment: @Rangutang Please ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that `contenders` is a pointer to an array of pointers.

There are three issues :

- you need to intialize `contenders`.
- the `dynamic_cast<>` check should use the original object
- `Professional` and `Exerciser` copy constructors are certainly defined as copying objects of type `Professional` and `Exerciser` respectively and not `Contender`.

Here a proposed correction:

```
Register::Register(const Register& original)
{
    kap = original.kap;
    currentAmount = original.currentAmount;
    contenders = new Contender[currentAmount];  // was missing
    for (int i = 0; i < currentAmount; i++)
    {
        if (Professional* pro = dynamic_cast<Professional*>(original.contenders[i]))
        {
            contenders[i] = new Professional(*pro);  // use the pro instead of contender
        }
        if (Exerciser* exe = dynamic_cast<Exerciser*>(original.contenders[i]))  
        {
            contenders[i] = new Exerciser(*exe);  // use exe instead of contender
        }
    }
    initiate(currentAmount);
}
```

Three recomendations though:

- you don't need to use `this->` to prefix all object variables.  Only in case of ambiguity with local variables of the member function itself.
- think of using `vector` instead of a pointer to an array
- the clone approach proposed in the comments would be a really nice and powerful alternative to your `dynamic_cast<>` checks

Comment: The type check surely should be on the source object, not the (empty) destination.